# the Chomsky hierarchy vs. classical complexity classes

Tags: computational-complexity, formal-grammar

What are the obvious (and less obvious) relationships between classical complexity classes like P,NP,PSPACE,EXP and the Chomsky hierarchy of grammars for the language $L$ in question,
context-free and  context-sensitive ? I have only one: regular is a strict subset of P.

Answer (score 0):

There are several relationships:

1. $\textsf{REG} = \textsf{DSPACE}(O(1)) = \textsf{NSPACE}(O(1))$. There are a couple steps in this proof:

- We may view DFAs as Turing Machines (TMs) that use $O(1)$ space. This gives us $\textsf{REG} \subseteq \textsf{DSPACE}(O(1))$. For the reverse inclusion, we effectively view the configuration graphs of TMs that use $O(1)$ space as DFAs.
- Change DFA to NFA, and we obtain that $\textsf{REG} = \textsf{NSPACE}(O(1))$
- Note that by Kleene's Theorem, DFAs and NFAs are equally powerful.

2. I am not entirely sure as to the best upper bound for $\textsf{CFL}$. However, $\textsf{LOGCFL}$ is the class of decision problems that are logspace reducible to CFLs. Clearly, $\textsf{CFL} \subseteq \textsf{LOGCFL}$. It is known that $\textsf{LOGCFL} = \textsf{SAC}^{1} \subseteq \textsf{AC}^{1}$.
3. $\textsf{CSL} = \textsf{NSPACE}(O(n))$. [Kur64]

[Kur64] S. Y. Kuroda. Classes of languages and linear-bounded automata, Information and Control 7:207-233, 1964.